# When does setting an Objective-C property double retain?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, memory-management, retain

Given the following code

```
@interface MyClass
{
   SomeObject* o;
}

@property (nonatomic, retain) SomeObject* o;

@implementation MyClass
@synthesize o;

- (id)initWithSomeObject:(SomeObject*)s
{
   if (self = [super init])
   {
      o = [s retain]; // WHAT DOES THIS DO? Double retain??
   }
   return self
}

@end
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It is not a double retain; `s` will only be retained once.

The reason is that you're not invoking the synthesized setter method within your initializer. This line:

```
o = [s retain];
```

retains `s` and sets `o` to be equal to `s`; that is, `o` and `s` point to the same object. The synthesized accessor is never invoked; you could get rid of the `@property` and `@synthesize` lines completely.

If that line were:

```
self.o = [s retain];
```

or equivalently

```
[self setO:[s retain]];
```

then the synthesized accessor would be invoked, which would retain the value a second time. Note that it generally not recommended to use accessors within initializers, so `o = [s retain];` is the more common usage when coding an `init` function.